# How to write unit tests for a Bot Framework v4 Dialog that requires the user to authenticate?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, botframework

I'm writing Unit Tests (C#) for Dialogs created with version 4 of the MS Bot Framework.
I'm wondering how to unit test a ComponentDialog containing a WaterfallDialog and a OAuthPrompt where one step of the WaterfallDialog requires the user to login using the OAuthprompt?

When I write a Unit Test for such a Dialog using the TestAdapter and TestFlow I get to following exception:

```
OAuthPrompt.GetUserToken(): not supported by the current adapter
```

This makes sense because the TestAdapter doesn't have a GetUserTokenAsync method like the BotFrameworkAdapter has (this method it called from OAuthPrompt.GetUserToken).

How can we work around this?

Comment: Hey, did you end up making a post about this? I can't find your post if you did on their repo, I would gladly make the post but I just want to make sure it's because it doesn't exist and not because I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The blunt, honest answer is that this will be extremely difficult to factor properly for unit testing today without making a large investment in working around the limitations of the APIs today.

As you pointed out in this specific case `OAuthPrompt` has *strong* ties to the `ITurnContext::Adapter` property being an instance of `BotFrameworkAdapter` specifically. This alone is "not good", but coupled with the fact that you can't actually override the APIs on `BotFrameworkAdapter` that the `OAuthPrompt` actually needs to call means you're completely stuck unless you use an advanced faking framework that allows for replacing non-virtual members.

Honestly, having looked into this for a bit, I don't think you can work around this right now. I would implore you to raise this an issue in the `botbuilder-dotnet` repo on GitHub and I will gladly chime in there with a recommendation to the team on how they could go about fixing this.

**UPDATE 8/15/2019**

Since the original answer, this was refactored to introduce an `IUserTokenProvider` interface which the `OAuthPrompt` now checks to see if the current `ITurnContext::Adapter` supports and, if so, calls through to its implementation. This means you can now mock this interface and implement the proper scenarios for tests.

Comment: Hey, do you know if there's any agreed on way of doing this now? I found some good links like https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Tests/OAuthPromptTests.cs but it looks like this is just for testing the OAuthPrompt itself rather than using the responses. Or maybe it has more info but it's late here... Any info is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @craigbot Hey, so, yes... there's some good news here actually! They realized the error of their ways and refactored to introduce an `IUserTokenProvider` interface which they check to see if the `ITurnContext::Adapter` supports and, if so, calls through to its implementation. This means you can now mock this interface and implement the proper scenarios for your tests. The tests you link to use the `TestAdapter` which itself implements this interface for example as does `BotFrameworkAdapter`. I will update my answer above with this detail.

Comment: This I still confusing for me... sorry. I don't really understand how to mock this. Could you provide a short example? If I say `hi` to my bot it triggers an OAuthPrompt. How could I then authenticate with the bot?

Answer (score -1):

There is an excellent Channel 9 Series that address this topic you can watch here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/DevOps-for-the-Bot-Framework/

Comment: That's 2 and a half years old. Still using V3, while V4 is a big improvement.